# Non capturing group getting captured in full match

Tags: regex, vbscript

- Sample string: `dadasd_37=12abc_dadasd_asdasdasd_asdas_asd`
- My regex: `(?:_37=)([^_]+)`
- What i am trying to get: `12abc` (anything that starts with `37=` and the word ends with `_`).

However, the full match is still coming as `_37=12abc`

Comment: "the word ends with _" That's not doing this *at all*. All `([^_]+)` is going is capture anything that isn't a `_`

Comment: Not an expert on regex but this pattern is doing what i want ... well very similar to what i want

Answer (score 3):

Capturing group matches are accessed via the [SubMatches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535741(v=vs.84).aspx) collection.

```
<%
Dim regex, matches, match, strSubject, strResult

strSubject = "dadasd_37=12abc_dadasd_asdasdasd_asdas_asd"

set regex = new RegExp
regex.IgnoreCase = True
regex.Pattern = "(?:_37=)([^_]+)"

set matches = regex.Execute(strSubject)

if matches.Count >= 1 then
    set match = matches(0)
    if match.SubMatches.Count >= 1 then
        strResult = match.SubMatches(0)
    else
        strResult = ""
    end If
else
    strResult = ""
end if

response.write "strResult:" & strResult & ""
%>
```

Comment: Is there a way that I only get the required text so that I don't have to process the sub matches

Comment: I don't know of any other way with vbscript.

Comment: Can you use javascript instead? http://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/989516

Comment: unfortunately not